# Scala Option type comparison

Tags: scala

I wrote a test case class

```
case class Test(name: String, emp:Option[Boolean])
```

When i create instances of it say

```
val t1 = Test("prince", Option(true))
val t2 = Test("prince", Option(true))
```

The comparison using `==` works just fine. I have a sample code from a colleague of mine who does comparison like this and I am unclear why does he have to do getOrElse in this case

```
t1.copy(emp = None) == t2.copy(emp = None) && t1.emp.getOrElse(false) == t2.emp.getOrElse(false)
```

Why is this better way of doing it?

Comment: The `copy` stuff seems quite, a way to fix a suboptimal  representation

Answer (score 2):

The second example will be true for cases where emp is `None` for one instance, and `Some(false)` for the other. Just doing `t1 == t2` would be false in that case.